# Sum all elements in a list without repeating already computed elements

Tags: recursion, erlang, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get to the result on what would be a double for-loop in another language (Java or JavaScript, for instance).

So the closest I can come up with is something like this:

```
1> L = [1,2,3].
[1,2,3]
2> R = [X + Y || X <- L, Y <- L].
[2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6]
3>
```

...but what I do really want is: `[3,4,5]`. I don't want to sum the elements that were already added:

```
A1 + A2
A2 + A3
A2 + A1 [already computed, position switched]
A2 + A3 [already computed, position switched]
A3 + A1
A3 + A2 [already computed, position switched]
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
[X+Y || X <- L, Y <- L, Y > X].
```

**Other solutions**

You essentially want two iterators walking alongside the same data structure and an accumulator to collect sums of distinctive elements. There is no reason why you wouldn't be able to mimic such iterators in Erlang:

```
-module(sum2).
-export([start/1]).

start(Max) ->
    L = lists:seq(1, Max),
    T = list_to_tuple(L),
    do_sum(T, 1, 2, size(T), []).

do_sum(T, X, S, S, A) when X + 1 =:= S ->
    lists:reverse([mk_sum(X, S, T) | A]);
do_sum(T, X, S, S, A) ->
    do_sum(T, X + 1, X + 2, S, [mk_sum(X, S, T) | A]);
do_sum(T, X, Y, S, A) ->
    do_sum(T, X, Y + 1, S, [mk_sum(X, Y, T) | A]).

mk_sum(X, Y, T) -> element(X, T) + element(Y, T).
```

The result:

```
7> c(sum2).
{ok,sum2}
8> sum2:start(3).
[3,4,5]
9> sum2:start(5).
[3,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,8,9]
```

There is actually a simpler solution if you don't have a list of elements that you want to sum but just integers:

```
-module(sum3).
-export([start/1]).

start(Max) -> do_sum(1, 2, Max, []).

do_sum(X, S, S, A) when X + 1 =:= S -> lists:reverse([X + S | A]);
do_sum(X, S, S, A) -> do_sum(X + 1, X + 2, S, [X + S | A]);
do_sum(X, Y, S, A) -> do_sum(X, Y + 1, S, [X + Y | A]).
```

Or even a simpler solution with just list comprehension:

```
4> L = [1, 2, 3].
[1,2,3]
5> [X+Y || X <- L, Y <- L, Y > X].
[3,4,5]
6> f().
ok
7> L = [1,2,3,4,5].
[1,2,3,4,5]
8> [X+Y || X <- L, Y <- L, Y > X].
[3,4,5,6,5,6,7,7,8,9]
```

Also check this question, [Erlang; list comprehension without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710978/erlang-list-comprehension-without-duplicates), which tackles a similar problem and has more ideas for possible solutions.